# iText 7 for .NET - New File is 10 times bigger then before using PdfCleanUp

Tags: c#, wpf, itext, visual-studio-2019, itext7

I wrote a small application on the fly to demonstrate something. I take an existing PDF and delete the data that is in two rectangles from the PDF and save it as a different file. The source file is 267KB in size once the contents are deleted out and the file is saved it is 2350KB in size.

I wrote it in a WPF application in Visual Studio 2019 and i use itext7 7.2.3 and itext7.pdfsweep 3.0.1.

What could be the reason for this? How do I go about finding the error?

I would be very grateful for ideas and tips. Maybe there is a more elegant way?

Thanks guys

```
string oldFile = "Path\example.pdf";
string newFile = "Path\example_new.pdf";

iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument pdfDoc = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument(new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader(oldFile), new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter(newFile));

 
iText.Kernel.Colors.DeviceRgb white = new iText.Kernel.Colors.DeviceRgb(255, 255, 255);
iText.Kernel.Colors.DeviceRgb grey = new iText.Kernel.Colors.DeviceRgb(220, 220, 220);

iText.PdfCleanup.PdfCleanUpLocation pdfcleanhead = new iText.PdfCleanup.PdfCleanUpLocation(1, new iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle(40, 774, 500, 27), white);
iText.PdfCleanup.PdfCleanUpLocation pdfcleancontent = new iText.PdfCleanup.PdfCleanUpLocation(1, new iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle(190, 682, 100, 15), grey);

iText.PdfCleanup.PdfCleanUpTool cleaner = new PdfCleanUpTool(pdfDoc);
cleaner.AddCleanupLocation(pdfcleanhead);
cleaner.AddCleanupLocation(pdfcleancontent);

cleaner.CleanUp();
pdfDoc.Close();
```

*Update:*

Thanks to mkl, I have also tried other PDFs. Unfortunately, I didn't get the idea at all yesterday afternoon. Of course, the error only occurs with the type of PDFs I want to edit with it.

A PDF created on the fly from Word doesn't get so huge and more or less keeps its file size.

The PDFs in question come from a report software. According to details they are created by a "combit List & Label Report GmbH" or "wPDF3by WPCubed GmbH". I can't share the data because it is customer data.

If I open the PDF before with LibreOffice Draw and export it again as PDF, the file is "only" 450kb in size when my code is done with deleting the data.

*Update 2:*

Thanks to André Lemos i tried SmartMode which

> This requires more memory, but reduces the file size of the resulting
> PDF document.

according to itextpdf.com

```
iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument pdfDoc = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument(new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader(oldFile), new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter(newFile).SetSmartMode(true));
```

The file had the same size as without SmartMode: 2113KB

Then I tried SetCompressionLevel. After what I found here 9 is the highest level:

```
iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument pdfDoc = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument(new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader(oldFile), new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter(newFile).SetCompressionLevel(9));
```

This allowed me to save the same file with only 2125 KB. So it helped a little bit... 8KB is of course hardly worth mentioning. Unfortunately.

*Update 3:*

I do all this just to replace a certain number I can extract from the file name twice in the document. If someone has an elegant solution for this I would also be very grateful!

*Update 4:*

After playing around with the tool that creates the PDFs, it seems I have found the problem. However, no solution yet.

The tool creates two diagrams in the PDFs. Without these diagrams the whole thing works without problems - even noticeably faster. With a image in the PDF file it has no problems.

*Update 5:*

A link to an example file which goes from 86kb to 600kb is in the comments.
It's smaller since there less diagrams.

*Update 6:*

@mkl's update after looking at the example file:

> "In essence what happens is that for being able to properly redact
> stroked lines, the cleanup tool replaces such stroked lines by thin,
> filled polygons. To these polygons the clipping is applied. Then these
> polygons are written back to the content stream. Usually these
> polygons use only a minimal number of vertices. In a PDF with very
> many stroked lines this should result in at worst a probably
> quadrupled size.For some reasons, though, in your file some of the
> resulting polygons have many many more vertices than necessary, and in
> the time I had I could not determine why."

So if anyone has a possible workaround, i would be more than happy!

Comment: Can you share the PDF to allow reproducing the issue?

Comment: Sadly i can't share them. But i updated my question!

Comment: Your question is specific to a problem that cannot be reproduced, and it is recommended that you delete the question, or give a minimal reproducible use case.

Comment: Maybe there is a way to reduce the file size of the created PDF file as a workaround with iTextSharp?

Of course I can delete the question if so are the rules...

Comment: not a lot to go on, but does [SmartMode](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/dotnet/7.2.3/classi_text_1_1_kernel_1_1_pdf_1_1_pdf_writer.html#ade51b90dd0bd508887c182f6fcd9b6e7) help?

Comment: I'm afraid without the document in question this is pure guesswork. You cannot create documents with test data entries, can you?

Comment: The files got a lot of watermarks and other stuff related to the customer. I am trying my best to create  a file which got same problems... Meanwhile i found out thats probably the problem of two diagrams in that file.

Comment: I managed to get a example PDF which goes from 86kb to 600kb. Should be the same issue. How can i send it to you @mkl?

Comment: If possible you should share it (e.g. using a public google drive or dropbox share) and post the link to it here.

Comment: Here is the PDF file: https://1drv.ms/b/s!Aj7x-HrNBqDw7EbEXNxcOq3kxTz7

Comment: Great. I'll test it today or tomorrow. One question before, though: does the size explode only for a specific set of redaction coordinates or for arbitrary ones? In the former case please provide values for `x, y, w, h`. As an aside, why do you clean the same area twice?

Comment: I don't replace the same area twice i just replace the coordinats for whatever reason.(40, 774, 500, 27) and (190, 682, 100, 15) are the ones i am using. - Sorry for that.

Comment: Ok, I looked into this a bit but I have not been able to identify the exact problem yet and I don't have more time to spare right now. In essence what happens is that for being able to properly redact stroked lines, the cleanup tool replaces such stroked lines by thin, filled polygons. To these polygons the clipping is applied. Then these polygons are written back to the content stream. Usually these polygons use only a minimal number of vertices. In a PDF with very many stroked lines this should result in at worst a  probably quadrupled size.

Comment: For some reasons, though, in your file some of the resulting polygons have many many more vertices than necessary, and in the time I had I could not determine why. Maybe I can look again later this week or next week.

Comment: Thank you @mkl for the time invested and explaining the issue. If I may ask, do you have a possible workaround? Maybe copy and paste the graph as a "screenshot" or similar?

Comment: A "screenshot" (rendering as bitmap) most likely would resolve the issue, the exploding file size, but such a bitmap is considerably less detailed than the original vector graphic.

Comment: You're absolutely right, of course. I'll try to implement that after work maybe. A real solution would be the best... Whereby that will probably be difficult with the given PDFs.

Comment: @mkl did you have any time yet to check to problem? Don't want to bother you but it would be cool to find a working solutio.

Comment: I've brought it to the attention of the iText team but i don't think it has a high priority.